# como separo las columnas con una línea divisoria las tablas de vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

hola tengo una duda como separo con una linea divisoria las columnas de una tabla de vuetify? quiero separarlas así se ve mejor pero no se hacerlo, alguna sugerencia? el código sería el de la página de vuetify una simple:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

y el script:

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 9.0
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
```

[image: por ejemplo que queden asi las lineas verticales]

Comment: ¿Hola a qué te refieres con una "con una linea divisoria las columnas? ¿Tienes una imagen donde representes gráficamente lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: hola ahi agregue una imagen como ejemplo